# How to check if a page is up or if user is connected to the domain

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I need some help in regards to a batch scripting. The purpose of the script is to open a web page when the user login into windows.

The web page is hosted into our local servers.

My issue is that the page still open(Obviously it does not display anything) even though the user is not connected to the network.

Unfortunately Ping is restricted. I am trying to either check if the webpage is accessible or if the user is connected to the network in order to launch the page.

Any ideas?

thanks & regards

Comment: If for some reason `ping` is restricted, use `telnet` instead. If it the host is online, it should return some data. (`400 Bad Request` or something like that)

Comment: thanks will try and see if it works

Comment: Telnet also is disabled ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Found below script that is doing the job.

```
@set @x=0 /*
:: ChkHTTP.cmd
 @echo off
  setlocal
  set "URL=http://10.0.0.23:8090/FeedBack/index.php"
  cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" %URL% | find "200" > nul
  if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k ""http://10.0.0.23:8090/FeedBack/index.php""
  ) else (
  echo 
     EXIT
  )
  goto :EOF

 JScript */
  var x=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0));x.send();
  while (x.ReadyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(1)};
  WSH.Echo(x.status)
```